# How can I create a contract with a default value

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm working on a marketplace, and want to instantiate an "Order" contract. The order needs to have a minimum value to be valid (for example an order of a $5 toy needs to have $5 of ether to be valid).

How can I instantiate a contract with a default value. The following is my attempt

```
new Order(buyer).value(msg.value)
```

Which gives me the error

```
Member "value" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract Order
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value can be sent [along with external function calls](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html#external-function-calls), but there's currently no syntax in Solidity to send value with contract instantiation. This could potentially be done using [inline assembly](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html#inline-assembly) and the `call` opcode, but you would have to construct the bytecode to be sent to the creation call yourself, which would be rather involved.

A simpler workaround would be to send the value in a separate call, and have the created contract check when appropriate if it's received the funds yet.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is still the case in 2018?